# Skype Whiteboard

Tags: skype

According to Skype's [blog](http://blogs.skype.com/en/2006/12/whiteboarding_with_skype_30_be.html), a whiteboarding feature was added in Skype 3. Using Skype 5 on Windows, I can't find this feature. Is it present?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Skype used to include a Sketch Pad out-of-the-box (available under the `Do More` menu). Then it became an extra that you had to download via the Skype Extras Manager (`Tools / Extras / Get Extras`). This feature is gone as well.

Now you can use **[IDroo](https://idroo.com/documentation/getting-started)**. It's an external application that integrates with Skype.

[image: IDroo-Skype integration]

Comment: Can't find sketch pad any more...

Comment: @MichaelTeper I have just updated my answer.